# iOS, is it ok to pop a ViewController from a navigationController, even if a request called from it isn't finished?

Tags: ios, networking, memory-leaks, uinavigationcontroller, exc-bad-access

Here is my situation:
I have a viewController whose main goal is to upload one photo. I use ReactiveCocoa like this:

```
- (IBAction)uploadTapped
{
    [[PhotosService uploadSignal] subscribeError:^(NSError *error) {
            NSLog(@"%@", error);
        } completed:^{
            NSLog(@"Upload completed");
    }];
    //I don't need to wait the upload result
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];`
}
```

Is it ok to pop the viewController even if the upload isn't finished? I wouldn't want to risk an EXC_BAD_ACCESS, or a memory leak because of that...

Thank you for your help

Comment: Depends what you're doing in the completion block, what you have there is fine

Comment: Thank you. I do nothing in the completion block. Maybe I will post a notification :
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] 
        postNotificationName:@"UploadCompleted" 
        object:nil];